# MVVM - Following a tutorial but not working as intended

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

> regarding :
>   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_wpf_data_bindings.htm

Fairly new to MVVM so I am following a Tutorial to learn more about it.

However I have reached a point in the Tutorial (that Link above)  where it does not appear to be working.  Basically when I update the text boxes the text Block is supposed to update also via Databindings

So here is my Code.

Model : https://pastebin.com/Lu2Cw2Py

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MIDB_MVVM.Model {
    public class InventoryModel
    {
    }
    public class InventoryItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Variables

        private string _barcode;
        private string _category;
        private string _location;
        private string _status;
        private string _sizeCase;
        private string _name;
        private string _manufacturer;
        private string _mpn;
        private string _supplier;
        private string _spn;
        private string _value;
        private string _tolerance;
        private string _voltage;
        private string _powerRating;
        private string _rohs;
        private string _description;

        #endregion

        public string Barcode
        {
            get
            {
                return _barcode;

            }
            set
            {
                if (_barcode != value)
                {
                    _barcode = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Barcode");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Category
        {
            get
            {
                return _category;

            }
            set
            {
                if (_category != value)
                {
                    _category = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Category");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Location
        {
            get
            {
                return _location;

            }
            set
            {
                if (_location != value)
                {
                    _location = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Status
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;   
            }
            set
            {
                if (_status != value)
                {
                    _status = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Sizecase
        {
            get
            {
                return _sizeCase;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_sizeCase != value)
                {
                    _sizeCase = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Sizecase");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Manufacturer
        {
            get
            {
                return _manufacturer;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_manufacturer != value)
                {
                    _manufacturer = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Manufacturer");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Mpn
        {
            get
            {
                return _mpn;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_mpn != value)
                {
                    _mpn = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Mpn");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Supplier
        {
            get
            {
                return _supplier;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_supplier != value)
                {
                    _supplier = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Supplier");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Spn
        {
            get
            {
                return _spn;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_spn != value)
                {
                    _spn = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("spn");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_value != value)
                {
                    _value = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Tolerance
        {
            get
            {
                return _tolerance;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_tolerance != value)
                {
                    _tolerance = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Tolerance");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Voltage
        {
            get
            {
                return _voltage;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_voltage != value)
                {
                    _voltage = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Voltage");
                }
            }
        }
        public string PowerRating
        {
            get
            {
                return _powerRating;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_powerRating != value)
                {
                    _powerRating = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("PowerRating");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Rohs
        {
            get
            {
                return _rohs;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_rohs != value)
                {
                    _rohs = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Rohs");
                }
            }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return _description;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_description != value)
                {
                    _description = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        public string CategoryLocation
        {
            get { return _category + " " + _location; }
        }

        private string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.InventoryDBConnString;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    } }
```

ViewModel: https://pastebin.com/fHtFVyx8

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

using MIDB_MVVM.Model;

namespace MIDB_MVVM.ViewModel {
    public class InventoryViewModel
    {
        public InventoryViewModel()
        {
            LoadInventory();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<InventoryItems> Inventories
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void LoadInventory()
        {
            ObservableCollection<InventoryItems> inventories = new ObservableCollection<InventoryItems>();

            inventories.Add(new InventoryItems
            {
                Barcode = "MRES01",
                Category = "Resistor",
                Description = "MRES01",
                Location = "ResBox", 
                Manufacturer = "RS",
                Mpn = "MRES01",
                Name = "SMDRes",
                PowerRating = "10",
                Rohs = "Yes",
                Sizecase = "0402",
                Value = "10",
                Status = "New",
                Supplier = "Farnell",
                Tolerance = "10", 
                Voltage = "10",
                Spn = "01234589"
            });
            inventories.Add(new InventoryItems
            {
                Barcode = "MRES02",
                Category = "Resistor",
                Description = "MRES02",
                Location = "ResBox",
                Manufacturer = "RS",
                Mpn = "MRES01",
                Name = "SMDRes",
                PowerRating = "20",
                Rohs = "Yes",
                Sizecase = "0603",
                Value = "20",
                Status = "New",
                Supplier = "Farnell",
                Tolerance = "20",
                Voltage = "20",
                Spn = "23456789"
            });
            inventories.Add(new InventoryItems
            {
                Barcode = "MRES03",
                Category = "Resistor",
                Description = "MRES03",
                Location = "ResBox",
                Manufacturer = "RS",
                Mpn = "MRES01",
                Name = "SMDRes",
                PowerRating = "30",
                Rohs = "Yes",
                Sizecase = "0805",
                Value = "30",
                Status = "New",
                Supplier = "Farnell",
                Tolerance = "30",
                Voltage = "30",
                Spn = "987654321"
            });

            Inventories = inventories;
        }

    } }
```

View/UserControl Xaml: https://pastebin.com/4bLFtss0

```
<UserControl x:Class="MIDB_MVVM.Views.InventoryView"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MIDB_MVVM.Views"
             xmlns:viewModel = "clr-namespace:MIDB_MVVM.ViewModel" 
             xmlns:vml ="clr-namespace:MIDB_MVVM.VML"
             vml:ViewModelLocator.AutoHookedUpViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <!--<UserControl.DataContext>
       <viewModel:InventoryViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>-->

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment = "Left">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = Inventories}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = Category, Mode = TwoWay}" 
                                     Width = "100" Margin = "3 5 3 5"/>

                            <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = Location, Mode = TwoWay }" 
                                     Width = "100" Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = CategoryLocation, Mode = OneWay}" 
                                       Margin = "0 5 3 5"/>

                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid> </UserControl>
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong here? Basically I am trying to figure out why my text block is not updating when a value is changed in my text boxes?

Comment: "Not working" doesn't work as a problem description. Please be more specific. What did you expect this to do, why did you expect it to do that, and what did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: As Described at the bottom of the post,  "Basically I am trying to figure out why my text block is not updating when a value is changed in my text boxes?" - Regarding the User Control or View

Comment: Also, is *all* of that code actually necessary to understanding the problem? Please read about how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set Category and Location properties you should raise PropertyChanged event twice, one with the property name and the other to notify that CategoryLocation had also changed:

```
    public string Category
    {
        get
        {
            return _category;

        }
        set
        {
            if (_category != value)
            {
                _category = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Category");
                RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryLocation");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return _location;

        }
        set
        {
            if (_location != value)
            {
                _location = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
                RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryLocation");
            }
        }
    }
```

Otherwise the view does not have a way to know that changing one of the two properties will affect the third.

Comment: Could not see this at all,  Will need to do a lot more reading about this.  Thank you greatly!